# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Login failed for user 'DRMDM'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to connect to a remote database for my website but I keep running into this error.. the connectionString section of my Web Config seems legit, I'm not sure whats the source of the problem is. Heres what my connectionString looks like.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DRMDM.db.11029316.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=DRMDM; User ID=DRMDM; Password='****'';" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DRBlogModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BlogModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BlogModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.BlogModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DRMDM.db.11029316.hostedresource.com;initial catalog=DRMDM;persist security info=True;user id=DRMDM;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Anything wrong with my Setup????

Comment: I'm hopefully assuming correctly that you can log into the database just fine with the same login and password using SSMS ?

Comment: There's also an extra ' at the end of the connection string, don't know if that's throwing things off or you just copy/pasted into here incorrectly.

Comment: Scott, yea i can log in with no problems, and ill checc it out

Comment: You are missing password in DRBlogModel connection string.

Comment: u sure??? i it required?

Comment: yes, it is required based on your DefaultConnection which is the same as DRBlogModel except that it is entity framework generated connection string.

Comment: after i put the password in i get 'Object not set to an instance on an object.' error.

Comment: That is a different error, it looks like you get null value from the db and try to do something with it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo:
Password='****'';

Guessing you put in asterisks for us, but there is an extra single tick